# Swift 5.+ - Making a class hashable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm very new to swift so please pardon any obvious misunderstandings. I've tried to research with no good answer.

I have a NavigationView with the following iteration

```
ForEach(listOfStuff, id: \.self)
```

The `listOfStuff` is defined as a struct conforming to Hashable and everything works just fine.

I wanted to change the struct to a class, and can't figure out how to make the class Hashable so that the `\.self` works (it keeps complaining that the class has to be Hashable)

Examples are old or keep talking about struct. I don't even know if I can even use a class in the ForEach? What do I do?

Thank you

Comment: You can certainly make a class hashable. But the problem is that it won't be hashable _automatically_ the way a struct is (when you declare conformance to Hashable). You have to implement hashability _yourself_ if you use a class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example for using class-based model in the described use-case. Tested with Xcode 11.4

```
class Stuff: Hashable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Stuff, rhs: Stuff) -> Bool {
        lhs.title == rhs.title
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
    }

    var title: String = ""
}

struct StaffView: View {
    let listOfStaff: [Stuff]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(listOfStaff, id: \.self) { stuff in
                Text(stuff.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved it for me. I was writing the hash function in my code, but never realized I had to also write the static func = ... and it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

See [Adopting Common Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/adopting_common_protocols) and [Hashable documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable), both of which outline the process of making it `Hashable`, as [outlined by Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61649557/1271826).

But you don’t have to make the whole thing `Hashable`. You could provide some property by which it could be identified, e.g.

```
class Item {
    let id: UUID
    let string: String

    init(string: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.string = string
    }
}
```

And

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, even better, make it `Identifiable`, e.g.

```
class Item: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let string: String

    init(string: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.string = string
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                Text(item.string)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can make it `Hashable` if you want, but `Identifiable` is simpler and sufficient for the purposes of `ForEach`.

Comment: This is very helpful as well, thank you. I'm beginning to understand this concept looking at the examples.